# DateTime format in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a column in a dataFrame to a TD format. 
The column looks like this (they are currently strings):

```
01/11/2012 00:00    
01/11/2012 01:00    
01/11/2012 02:00
```

This is what I have done now:

```
df['Sdate'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Sdate'], format='%d%m%y %H:%M.%f')
```

But, it throws an error saying,

```
time data '01/11/2012 00:00' does not match format '%d%m%y %H:%M.%f' (match)
```

Not, sure why it does that. Isn't HH:MM 00:00 - 23:00?

Or, am I missing something really stupid here?

Comment: You're missing `/`, you don't need a microsecond directive, and `%y` should be `%Y`; instead use `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst` parameter:

```
df['Sdate'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Sdate'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
                Sdate
0 2012-11-01 00:00:00
1 2012-11-01 01:00:00
2 2012-11-01 02:00:00
```

If want specify format:

```
df['Sdate'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Sdate'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
print (df)
                Sdate
0 2012-11-01 00:00:00
1 2012-11-01 01:00:00
2 2012-11-01 02:00:00
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.
Can you explain what effect the 'dayfirst=True' has?

Comment: If omit it it will be parsed `2012-01-11 00:00:00` if all dates are not claer like `2012-11-21 00:00:00`. So it can be obviusly omit, but if only a few dates and not clear `DDMMYY` vs `MMDDYY` it is helpful.